# Differences between scanf and getchar in C

Tags: c, scanf, getchar

I was trying to explain to my friend something about C coding and he asked me why his code (with "scanf") didn't work.

#include

```
int main() {
char x=scanf("%c",&x);
printf("%c\n",x);
return 0;
}
```

and this one yes

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
int k;
char x=getchar
printf("%c\n",x);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Duplicate of [confused-about-getchar-and-scanf](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20970622/confused-about-getchar-and-scanf)

Comment: What exactly didn't work? “doesn't work” is not an error description.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `scanf` completes, `x` contains the character that was read.  However,  that value is immediately overwritten when `x` is assigned the return value of `scanf`, which is the number of items successfully matched or EOF in the event of an error.

If you call `scanf` without assigning the return value to `x` you should get the expected result.

For example, this should work.

```
char x;
scanf("%c",&x);
```