# Why am I getting the following output in this simple code?

Tags: c, output

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
    {
        int i,l,*A;char C;
        A=(int*)malloc(5*4);
        for(i=0;i<5;i++)
            scanf("%d",A+i);
        scanf("%c",&C);
        scanf("%d",&l);
        printf("%d%c\n",l,C);

return 0;
}
```

Input: 5 4 3 3 9
       r 1

I expect the output to be 1r.  But I am getting the output as 21473443
84...i.e. garbage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your example, `%c` reads the space before the `r`, and the subsequent `scanf("%d")` fails to read an integer (since it's presented with `r 1`).

To verify this, examine the return value of `scanf()`: it is [the number of items successfully matched and stored](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10469649/367273), so the final `scanf()` will return zero.

P.S. In the `malloc()` (or anywhere else for that matter) you should not assume that `sizeof(int) == 4`.

Comment: And there must also be a `free` call to the `malloc`'ed pointer.

Comment: How do I verify the return value value of scanf()?

Comment: You assign it to a variable (as you would with the return value of any other function), and then examine the variable (as you would with any other variable).

Answer (score 1):

For `%c` conversion specifier, scanf does not omit whitespaces as it does for `%d` for example. You have to tell scanf to skip whitespaces and then read first non-whitespace character. Here's your fixed code.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
    {
        int i,l,*A;char C;
        A=malloc(5*sizeof(int));
        for(i=0;i<5;i++)
            scanf("%d",A+i);
        scanf(" %c",&C);
        //     ^ here
        scanf("%d",&l);
        printf("%d%c\n",l,C);
        free(A);  // remember to free what you've malloc'd

return 0;
}
```

Since you are asking how to verify return value from scanf, see prototype of scanf:

> int scanf(const char *format, ...);

As you can see, it returns int. Man page says even more about return value:

> RETURN VALUE
>  These functions return the number of input items
>   successfully matched and assigned, which  can be fewer than provided
>   for, or even zero in the event of an early matching failure.

This part I will leave for you to do it. I hope that it is now clear how to check scanf's return value.

Answer (score 0):

(1)Give space before `%c` in scanf (i.e) `scanf(" %c",&C);`

(2)Scanf function  return the number of input items successfully matched and assigned.

To check scanf return value,

```
void main
  {
    int a,b,c,d;
    a=scanf("%d%d%d",&b,&c,&d);
    printf("a=%d\n",a);//a=3
    a=scanf("%d",&b);
    printf("a=%d",a);//a=1
  }
```