# How to differentiate a two digit number(65) from a character ('a')?

Tags: c

I have an application which gets 10 different numbers (which are less than 100) as input. If any thing other than number is entered, it should display "Invalid input"

ex: If I enter 'C' which is not a number between 1 to 100, Program should display "Invalid input"

I don't want to compare the input with all the characters and special symbols

If the number is a single digit number, isdigit() or isalpha() does the job.

How can I solve this?

Comment: take the input as a string, f.e. `"65"` or `"C"` and run your isdigit-check on the string until reaching not a digit or the end of the string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would just use something like this: `scanf("%d", &variable)` and check [return value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10469643/value-returned-by-scanf-function-in-c) of this function. It will work unless you have something other than digit on stdin. You can put this in the loop and catch this error using return value of `scanf()` function.

Answer (score 2):

> If the number is a single digit number, isdigit() or isalpha() does
>   the job.

But you want to check a number between `1` and `99` (more than one digit), in this case you can use `isdigit()` in a loop, [scanf](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html) or [strtol](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtol.3.html):

An example using `strtol`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    char str[32];
    char *end;
    long num;

    printf("Enter a number between 1 and 99:\n");
    fgets(str, sizeof str, stdin);
    num = strtol(str, &end, 10);
    if ((num < 1) || (num > 99) || (*end != '\n')) {
        printf("Error\n");
    } else {
        printf("%ld\n", num);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I suppose you get the numbers in a loop right? If it is, you can add an if-statement to control the inserted values.

```
if (num>=0 && num <=100)
//code
else
printf("Invalid input");
```

And you insert this code in the loop after the `scanf("%d",&variable)` function.

Comment: -1: UB when the input is not a number (question explicitly asks about this case); errors going to stdout and without a newline (also negatively impacts buffering behaviour); question says "less than 100" (i.e. excluding 100) and "between 1 and 100" (excluding 0) so your check is off-by-one on both sides.