# Is it possible for an if statement to say if something is not entered?

Tags: c, if-statement, stdio

I'm doing a project and I'm just curious to know if it is possible to have a line that says "if something is not entered" and a prompt statement would be followed.
For example,

```
if(id_ == NULL){printf("John Doe is absent.")}.
```

Just a curious question because I want to explore C programming a bit more.

Comment: what is the the input type? `int`? `float`? `char`? `char` array?

Comment: What does "something is not entered" mean? What kind of thing? Entered where?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with `scanf` (or similar functions: fscanf, sscanf...).
Assuming id_ is an `int`:

```
if(scanf("%d",&id_)!=1){
      printf("John Doe is absent.");
}
```

These functions return the number of input items  successfully  matched and assigned.

see top voted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10469643/value-returned-by-scanf-function-in-c) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

void input_id(int **id){
    int num;
    printf("input id:");
    if(scanf("%d", &num)==1)
        **id = num;
    else
        *id = NULL;
}

int main(void){
    int id;
    int *id_ = &id;

    input_id(&id_);
    if(id_ == NULL){
        printf("John Doe is absent.\n");
    } else {
        printf("id : %d\n", id);
    }
    return 0;
}
```