# Infinite loop in C

Tags: c, loops, scanf

The program should accept input values on stdin until EOF is reached. The input is guaranteed to be well-formed and contain at least one valid floating point value.

Sample input:

`3.1415
 7.11
-15.7`

Expected output:

`3 3 4
 7 7 8
 -16 -16 -15
 Done.`

```
#include <stdio.h>  
#include <math.h>  
#include <stdlib.h>  

int main(void) 
{  
    for(;;)  
    {  
        float b;          
        scanf("%f", &b);  
        printf("%g %g %g\n",floor(b), round(b), ceil(b));  
        int i=0;  
        int result = scanf("%d", &i);  

        if( result == EOF)  
        {  
            printf("Done.\n");  
            exit(0);  
        }  

     }  
    return 0;  
}
```

My program only runs one time. After that it outputs `0 1 1`

Comment: Why the second `scanf()`?  Shouldn't you just check the return from the first one?

Comment: As is, you scan `3.1415` into `f`, `7` into `i`, `.11` into `f`, `-15` into `i`, `.7` into `f`, then finish... and should get `"3 3 4\n0 0 1\n0 1 1\nDone.\n"` as output (your second `scanf()` eats the beginnings of most of the input numbers -- as much as can be interpreted as an integer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to stay with the `scanf`, you can use the return value to detect a erroneous/EOF input:

```
#include <stdio.h>  
#include <math.h>  
#include <stdlib.h>  

int main(void) 
{  
    int result = 0;
    for(;;)  
    {  
        float b;
        result = scanf(" %f", &b); 
        if(result == EOF)
            break;

        printf("%g %g %g\n",floor(b), round(b), ceil(b));  
     }  
     printf("Done");
    return 0;  
}
```

[Try it here.](http://ideone.com/VPKqhN)

Also a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10469643/value-returned-by-scanf-function-in-c) is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I think your second `scanf` is the problem, like others have already told you. How about doing it this way? The `getchar()` call seems to pick up the EOF more reliably.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>


int main (void) {
    float b;

    for (;;) {
        scanf("%f",&b);
        printf("%g %g %g\n",floor(b),round(b),ceil(b));
        if (getchar() == EOF)
            break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```