# How to properly validate how many inputs were read in scanf

Tags: c, scanf

How do i properly see how many inputs were read in my scanf function? when i run the below code it does not display the result, is this because i dont have 2 inputs read from scanf or some other reason
here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h> 

int main()
{
float numberOne;
float numberTwo;

scanf("%f %f", &numberOne, &numberTwo);
float result = numberOne + numberTwo;

int howManyRead = scanf("%f %f", &numberOne, &numberTwo);

if ( howManyRead == 2)
{
    printf("%f", &result);
}   
else
{
    printf("invalid input");
}
sleep(10);

}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10469643/value-returned-by-scanf-function-in-c Hope this can help.

Comment: Did you mean to call scanf twice?

Comment: "how many inputs were read in my scanf function?" --> How do you want to the user to indicate that input is complete? By entering text and then a `'\n'`?  Should input `"123\n"` report only 1 number was entered or wait for the next line of input like `"456\n"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two calls of `scanf` in your code. The result of the first call is ignored, while the result of the second one is checked.

When you enter two numbers, the first `scanf` returns 2, which your code ignores. After that the call to second `scanf` tries to read two additional numbers.

You can fix this by removing the first call to `scanf`:

```
float numberOne, numberTwo;
if ( scanf("%f %f", &numberOne, &numberTwo) == 2) {
    float result = numberOne + numberTwo;
    printf("%f", result);
} else {
    printf("invalid input");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You are not using the return value of `scanf()` in the expected way. It is there to indentify the success / failure in scanning and take a decision based on that.

There are three things you need to do.

- Remove the two lines

  ```
  scanf("%f %f", &numberOne, &numberTwo); 
  float result = numberOne + numberTwo;
  ```

  This is because, without a check, if you try to use the destination variables, there values may be indeterminate in case `scanf()` fails. Also, there are repeated `scanf()`s which are plain wrong and not needed.
- Add the line `float result = numberOne + numberTwo;` inside the condition block `if ( howManyRead == 2)`.
- Remove the `&` from the `printf` call: `printf("%f", result);`

Comment: thanks @melpomene, that makes three points, updated already. :)