# Scanf not providing expected output

Tags: c, scanf, user-input

```
#include <stdio.h>
int Second_minimum;
int GetSecondMinimum(int,int,int);
int main(){ 
  int a = scanf("%d",&a);
  int b = scanf("%d",&b);
  int c = scanf("%d",&c);
  int Secondminimum=GetSecondMinimum(a,b,c);
  printf("%d",Secondminimum);
}
int GetSecondMinimum(int x,int y,int z){
  if(x>y && x<z){
    Second_minimum=x;}
  else if(x>z && x<y){
    Second_minimum=x;}
  else if(y>x && y<z){
    Second_minimum=y;}
  else if(y<x && y>z){
    Second_minimum=y;}
  else if(z>x && z<y){
    Second_minimum=z;}
  else if(z<x && z>y){
    Second_minimum=z;}
  return Second_minimum;
}
```

The above code is not printing on the basis of user-input.

For example, if I am passing a direct value to the function, it is showing the proper answer.

It is printing `20` if I am passing `GetSecondMinimum(20,10,30)` but it is not printing if I am passing parameters this way:

```
a=20;b=10;c=30;
GetSecondMinimum(a,b,c)
```

Comment: `int a = scanf("%d",&a);` you are assign return value of `scanf`.

Comment: Reading the man page of scanf: On success, these functions return the number of input items successfully matched and assigned;  this  can  be fewer than provided for, or even zero, in the event of an early matching failure.

Comment: How to pass the user-input through the function and print the result?

Comment: it is printing 0

Comment: Please read the [manpage for scanf](https://www.manpagez.com/man/3/scanf/). The return value is not the same as one of the parsed values. (If you scan 5 integers, which one would you expect as return value anyway?). You should also check that return value if you were able to read any value at all. You probably only got 1 value because there is a `\n` left in the input buffer.

Comment: Basically: `int FOO = scanf("%d",&FOO)` -> `scanf("%d",&FOO)`. BTW your question title _"function is not printing right value"_ is misleading, it should be _"scanf is not working as I expect"_

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
int Second_minimum;
int GetSecondMinimum(int,int,int);
int main()
{ 
  int a,b,c;
  scanf("%d%d%d",&a,&b,&c);
  int Secondminimum=GetSecondMinimum(a,b,c);
  printf("%d",Secondminimum);
}
int GetSecondMinimum(int x,int y,int z)
{
  if(x>y && x<z)
  {
    Second_minimum=x;
  }
  else if(x>z && x<y)
  {
    Second_minimum=x;
  }
  else if(y>x && y<z)
  {
    Second_minimum=y;
  }
  else if(y<x && y>z)
  {
    Second_minimum=y;
  }
  else if(z>x && z<y)
  {
    Second_minimum=z;
  }
  else if(z<x && z>y)
  {
    Second_minimum=z;
  }
  return Second_minimum;
}
```

Output :

```
20 10 30
20
```

Your Doubt :

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main ()
{
  int a;
  int b;
  a = scanf("%d", &b);  //lets input b=23
  printf("b = %d",b);
  printf("\na = %d", a);
  return 0;
}
```

Output :

```
b = 23
a = 1
```

`int a = scanf("%d",&a)`; is returning the number of successfully scanned items(in this case 'b') thus if you do this and input the value of `b=23`, then it will return `1` which is the number of scanned items. Hence, a=1;
Here `a` will contain the return value of `scanf` function.

**scanf returns the number of successfully scanned items.**

Ref: [What does the scanf function return?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10469643/what-does-the-scanf-function-return)