# Output of Code is 114 I can't figure out why

Tags: c, output

I'm new to programming and I'm learning about loops and if-else statements.  For the code below, I need an explanation about why the final output is `114` when I run it in VSCode. I know that for the third iteration, since `i`=2, `2%2` is false, so it goes to the else section. `one * two` is supposed to be equal to 112. How did this become 114?? I know that `total+= one*two` is supposed to be `total = total + one*two` right? That's the definition of `+=` operator. I just can't figure out why the output is 114 here. ChatGPT cant even answer.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

#include <stdio.h>

#define SZ 3 

int main(void)
{
    int i, one = 0, two = 0, total = 0;

    printf("Enter two whole numbers separated by a space: "); // user enters 56 2
    total = scanf("%d %d", &one, &two);

    for (i = 0; i < SZ; i++)
    {
        if (i % two) 
        {
            total = two + one / total;
        }
        else
        {
            total += one * two;
        }
    }

    printf("total is equal to %d\n", total);

    return 0;
}
```

I expected the code to get the output of 116 but it always gets the 114 answer. I've already corrected the condition.

Comment: Hint: what does `total` get set to on the first and second iterations?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Have you tried, for example, using a debugger to step through the code to see what parts are executed, and what the results values of total are at each step?

Answer (score 3):

Let's consider the calculation of the program:

1. As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10469643/what-does-the-scanf-function-return) <sup>(thanks to @John Omielan's comment)</sup>, since we have `total = scanf("%d %d", &one, &two);`, and the input is `56 2`, the initial value of `one`, `two` and `total` is 56, 2, 2.
2. When `i` is 0, the program runs the else section, `one * two` equals to 112, so `total` is increased by 112, and now it's 2 + 112 = 114.
3. When `i` is 1, the program runs the if section, `two + one / total` is `2 + 56 / 114`. First, notice that `operator/` is prior than `operator+` in C, so it will be first calculated. Second, if the two numbers of the `/` calculation is both integers, the fractional part would be abandoned, so the result of `56 / 114` is `0`. Then, the result of `2 + 56 / 114` is `2 + 0`, and that's `2`, so the value of `total` is now `2`.
4. When `i` is 2, the program runs the else section, `one * two` equals to 112, so `total` is increased by 112, because **it was `2` before the addition, it should be `2 + 112` = `114` now**.

In an conclusion, the key point is that because **it was `2` before the addition, it should be `2 + 112` = `114` now**, and don't forget that if you use `operator+=`, the program increases the variable by the value after the operater, but *not* just setting the variable to the value after the operator.

Comment: Note that, with your point #1, such as explained in [What does the scanf function return?](/q/10469643), since the code has `total = scanf("%d %d", &one, &two);`, then the initial value of `total` is 2, not 0. Thus, the new value of `total` becomes 114 instead of 112. Nonetheless, in your point #2, we still get `56 / 114` being 0, so the new result of `total` is still 2.

Comment: Can someone explain why Total is 2?

Since Total = 56, 2 in the code: total=scanf("%d %d", &one, &two)

Is it because there are two values 56 and 2?

Everything else makes sense to me except this part

Comment: @AlyssaManlosa, see [What does the scanf function return?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10469643/what-does-the-scanf-function-return).

Comment: @AlyssaManlosa, the `scanf` function return the number of input items successfully  matched and assigned.

Answer (score 2):

It is the order of math operations. C++ follows the standard math operations that you would see in math.

```
total = two + one / total;
```

should be..

```
total = (two + one) / total;
```

Comment: "total = (two + one) / total;"  will give you the 112 you came up with. Whereas "total = two + one / total;"  will the 114 result that running it gives you. BTW - "New contributor" helps "New contributor" =)

Comment: Question was tagged ```C```, and **NOT** ```C++```.

Comment: @Iman Abdollahzadeh - Thank you for the clarification. I appreciate your attention to the tagging detail. Perhaps a gentle reminder could be even more welcoming to all community members. For instance: "Hello, Bemmerbox, welcome to StackOverflow! It appears the code is discussed in the context of C, as indicated by the tag at the bottom of the post. While the code might also run in C++, specifying it as C can help avoid confusion, especially for those new to programming languages. I just wanted to highlight this. I hope this helps, and we look forward to more StackOverflow contributions!"